# nautilus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tracker-2.0/libtracker-data.so.0: undefined symbol: sqlite3_bind_pointer

Tags: nautilus, sqlite3

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and I can't get Nautilus to work. I get the following error when I launch it from the command line:

```
nautilus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tracker-2.0/libtracker-data.so.0: undefined symbol: sqlite3_bind_pointer
```

I tried uninstalling and purging and reinstalling `nautilus`, `sqlite3`, and GNOME and it didn't work. Please help!! I found this bug reported elsewhere, however, I didn't find a solution for it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Nautilus doesn't launch from the GUI, with no on screen error, and I get this issue when running it from the command line.

Answer (score 4):

This problem was solved for me following the recommendation under this link posted [by sunnysharan369 in Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2393754&p=13813632#post13813632):

> 1.) wget https://sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-autoconf-3250200.tar.gz
>
> 2.) tar -xvf sqlite-autoconf-3250200.tar.gz
>
> 3.) cd sqlite-autoconf-3250200
>
> 4.) ./configure
>
> 5.) make
>
> 6.) sudo make install

Comment: This fix my problem with nautilus when the evening before I was trying to install sqlite3 for arm. I destroyed something. Your solution fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

For `sqlite-autoconf` new updateyou can visit the project's webpage: https://sqlite.org/download.html

You can download the latest package from this link: https://sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3340000.tar.gz