# Error while trying to run "gnome-control-center display"

Tags: 20.04, gnome-control-center

I have an issue opening the settings on my Ubuntu, getting back this:

gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: sqlite3_errstr

I tired fixing it using those following links:

[Made a mistake and deleted just some of the files in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ how do I restore the files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987605/made-a-mistake-and-deleted-just-some-of-the-files-in-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu)

[Unable to open gnome-control-center in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213155/unable-to-open-gnome-control-center-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Also tried to:

sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center

and to reinstall my desktop

nothing works

Any ideas?

Comment: Did it ever work? If so, what were the changes you made to the system before it stopped working?

Comment: Not sure, i tried to install sqlite3 last week, i tried to remove it, did not help.

Comment: Solved with :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087345/nautilus-symbol-lookup-error-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-tracker-2-0-libtracker